# Difference between tuples that may have duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have two tuples, which may or may not have duplicated elements. I want to remove elements of tuple `a` that also occur in tuple `b`, taking into account multiplicity. That is,

```
a = (1, 2, 3), b = (2, 3, 4) => (1)
a = (1, 2, 2, 3), b = (2, 3, 4) => (1, 2)
a = (1, 2, 3), b = (2, 2, 3, 4) => (1)
```

I want to use these tuples as keys for @lrucache, so I need a hashable type.

I'm not even sure how to do this by hand if there is no better way.

Edit: This is a Python question, which I realized might not be obvious.

Comment: Does the order of the elements matter?  Will they always be ascending as in your examples?

Comment: @MarkRansom a in the examples above will be sorted, but b may not be.

Comment: How large are the sets?  The obvious brute force method of using a loop will work, as long as you don't have 50,000 elements.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry, what is the obvious brute force method? (These are very short lists)

Comment: @Goku I think a loop is still necessary over the resulting Counter to extract the new tuple. That's not a problem for me as the lists are very short, but is there a better way?

Comment: @rogerl. `tuple((c(a)-c(b)).elements())` will directly give you tuple. No need for a loop i guess.

Comment: @Goku Oh. Very nice. Thanks. Want to write that up as an answer so we can close this?

Comment: Yes it is already there in my answer at the end :) I have removed the unnecessary part to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract elements with their frequencies using Counter.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter as c
a = (1, 2, 2, 3)
b = (2, 3, 4)



print(tuple((c(a)-c(b)).elements()))
(1,2)
```

---

Taking more complex example

```
from collections import Counter as c
a = (1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5)
b = (2, 3, 4)



print(tuple((c(a)-c(b)).elements()))

#outputs

(1, 2, 2, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the obvious brute force method.  Convert 'a' to list, delete the elements one by one, convert the remainder back.  I've also added the "collections" scheme as a comparison:

```
from collections import Counter

def set_subtract( a, b ):
    a = list(a)
    for el in b:
        if el in a:
            a.remove(el)
    return tuple(a)

def collect(a, b):
    c = Counter(a) - Counter(b)
    l = [[k]*v for k,v in c.items() if v > 0]
    return tuple(sum(l,[]))

a = (1, 2, 3)
b = (2, 3, 4)
print(set_subtract(a,b))
print(collect(a,b))
a = (1, 2, 2, 3)
b = (2, 3, 4)
print(set_subtract(a,b))
print(collect(a,b))
a = (1, 2, 3)
b = (2, 2, 3, 4)
print(set_subtract(a,b))
print(collect(a,b))
```

Output:

```
(1,)
(1,)
(1, 2)
(1, 2)
(1,)
(1,)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Multiset` container implemented in the package [`multiset`](https://multiset.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). The `-` operator is exactly what you need.

```py
from multiset import Multiset

a = Multiset((1, 2, 3))
b = Multiset((2, 3, 4))
c = tuple(a - b)
print(f"{c = }") # c = (1,)

a = Multiset((1, 2, 2, 3))
b = Multiset((2, 3, 4))
c = tuple(a - b)
print(f"{c = }") # c = (1, 2)

a = Multiset((1, 2, 3))
b = Multiset((2, 2, 3, 4))
c = tuple(a - b)
print(f"{c = }") # c = (1,)
```